# How to update Chromecast MediaMetadata during radio stream?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I recently added the ability to (chrome) cast a radio stream (audio/aac) from my Android radio app. The initial casting works as expected; the stream begins playing on the selected chromecast device and the MediaMetadata I provided is displayed in the [Cast Dialog](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist/cast-dialog) and, if casting to a TV or monitor, on the screen via the receiver app.

When I initially cast the stream I provide the MediaMetadata of the currently playing track. Within my Android app I have a service that can notify me when the track has changed and sends out an updated metadata. The issue I'm having is that I'm struggling to find a way to notify the Chromecast device of this update so that the TV will update the track metadata, show the right title/artist & artwork. 
The only partial, hacky way I've found of doing it so far is by calling  [`RemoteMediaClient.load`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient.html#load(com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaInfo,%20com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaLoadOptions)) again with the same stream info and the updated MediaMetadata. This approach is not acceptable as it causes the stream to reload, temporarily halting the playing. 
I do not see any methods in the [RemoteMediaClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient) that allow for simply updating the MediaMetadata.

The only other post I can find on here that somewhat relates to this is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831209/update-chromecast-mediametadata), however this now 4 years old and refers to an older version of the SDK that has since been deprecated.

I'm pretty sure the functionality I desire is possible as I've seen this behaviour in other radio apps that include the Chromecast feature.

Comment: You can file an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Anyone had any luck? I have the same situation.

Comment: I'm also looking for the exact same thing.